# Run PHP file without open the page

Tags: xcode

I need to run a PHP file from my app without opening the internet browser. What I am doing at the moment is:

```
NSString *theUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyWebSite.com/PHPFile.php?theMessage=%@&theToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", myString];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:theUrl]];
```

The code above is working, but it takes me to the internet browser.
Can any one help me in this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and it is working without opening the browser:

```
 // call the current user
    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"SaveUserName"];
    NSLog(@"User name to delete %@ ",myString);

    NSString *queryString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://MyWebSite.com/phpFile.php?theMessage=%@&theToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", myString];


    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest
                              requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:
                                              queryString]
                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                              timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
    if (con) {
        _receivedData=[NSMutableData data];


    } else {
        //something bad happened
    }
```

I hope the answer is helpful to someone.

Comment: What does "run a PHP file from my app" mean, what are you trying to accomplish.